# URL for Verifying PayPal IPN messages

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

My PaypalIPN.php has this line:

**const VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';**

My Buy Now button says different:

**"https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"**

**Is that correct with one going to ipnpb. and one going to [www.paypal.com](http://www.paypal.com)**
Orders are scarce, there's something wrong somewhere, I'm doing a process of illimintation, can anyone verify the above?
If yours is working OK, can you take a look por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Either URL can work, but the ipnpb one is newer and preferred, per the current [IPN documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/ipn/IPNImplementation/).

Comment: Thanks for that Preston, I was thinking they were conflicting because of PayPal's recent move to the Cloud and the outsoucing of the payment gateway to India which is outside of paypal.com's domain.
Funny how no-one tells you about this, it's just left for us to find out when our shops stop working!

Comment: The old URL is supported for backwards compatibility and apparently still works from old IPN scripts/code written many years ago, it's just not recommended anymore as the www domain's real purpose is to serve the PayPal website; it's not set aside specifically for IPN postbacks

Comment: IPN is a ~20 year old technology and unnecessary for current integrations that capture with an API call, though a similar asynchronous service called Webhooks exists and can be useful for post-checkout events like being notified of refunds, disputes, or new subscription payments that take place on a future cycle

Comment: Thank you Preston, I am using the IPN in conjunction with the Legacy html Buy Now buttons because it's the only thing available to me for sending my buyer the download link instantly to his/her email box.
I am linked up to the webhooks but I think they only give me information.

Comment: Why are buy now buttons the only thing that allow you to send a download link? I would use a full stack server integration of https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ , and have the backend capture route send your email on successful capture, right before forwarding that capture response on to the client button JS code that called it

Comment: With such an integration, it all happens synchronously -- there is no need to wait for an asynchronous IPN message to post to your server after the fact.

Comment: Thank you, it's all  becoming a bit clearer now, your suggestion seems the simplest way to go, I should move on a bit more!